# Filling gaps based on a trend from another column in Python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have one station with daily measurements of some feature. But there are several other places, where we measure the same feature about 10 to 14 times a year. Now I have to fill the gaps with values based on the trends of the reference station.

I've made a simplified version of data in the table below.

Problem 1: These values are not precisely related throughout the year: 100 on ref_station may match different values on another (e.g. 65 one day, 75 another time).

Problem 2: Between equal values on expeditionary measurements there can be slight changes on the reference station (6th to 9th jan.), so that can't be a simple linear interpolation between known values.

| Date | ref_station | exped_1 | exped_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 100 | 65 |  |
| 2022-01-02 | 110 |  | 130 |
| 2022-01-03 | 115 |  |  |
| 2022-01-04 | 105 |  |  |
| 2022-01-05 | 110 |  |  |
| 2022-01-06 | 100 | 75 |  |
| 2022-01-07 | 105 |  |  |
| 2022-01-08 | 102 |  |  |
| 2022-01-09 | 100 | 75 |  |
| 2022-01-10 | 110 |  | 165 |

Below the same table filled with some values, that could be acceptable. I'm aware the method is not very reliable in the first place, but I just need a somewhat smoothed graph at the end.

| Date | ref_station | exped_1 | exped_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 100 | 65 |  |
| 2022-01-02 | 110 | *73* | 130 |
| 2022-01-03 | 115 | *78* | *140* |
| 2022-01-04 | 105 | *76* | *136* |
| 2022-01-05 | 110 | *77* | *150* |
| 2022-01-06 | 100 | 75 | *143* |
| 2022-01-07 | 105 | *76* | *150* |
| 2022-01-08 | 102 | *75* | *149* |
| 2022-01-09 | 100 | 75 | *148* |
| 2022-01-10 | 110 |  | 165 |

I've only tried the standard Pandas *interpolate* function with different methods.
But I assume instead that I need to somehow move the 'box' between the known values and calculate some proportions in that box? Maybe I have calculate line by line? Or maybe there's some funcion which could be helpful for me?

Comment: I'm at loss with the interpolation method. How can 110 map to 73 and 77 in the first streak for `exped_1`? Can you show how these values are calculated manually?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CodeDifferent Well, that's the main problem - the data before was never truly interpolated. It's filled manualy, so the final form of graph is smooth and without 'stairs' (before and after time of the real measurement). 
So there's no one good solution - I'm just looking for a method, which give me acceptable, not perfect outcome.